# What Causes Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcuts to Change? (VS2019)

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, 'find all references' was **Ctrl + Shift + F12**, now seems to be **Ctr + K + R**

Is this a user setting or changed during a new build of VS?

Comment: This happened to me too - I blame the Cloud settings synchronization feature being on te fritz. (I really dislike how it doesn't let us select *which* settings get cloud-syncd instead of all of them).

Comment: It's happened to me many times, usually after installing a VS add-in.  For this reason I perform an export of VS settings to my DropBox folder regularly.   I don't use VS's Cloud sync.

Comment: For reference, use Tools > Keyboard > Default to reset to the Shift + F12 setting I am referring to

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut is still same. I think you might have installed extensions like ReSharper, so it might be due to that. Please uninstall extension and then check.

**Reference:** https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/530592/view.html

Answer (score 0):

The change could have many reasons: Change of keyboard language, the configuration file might have changed something or an extension was installed.